# gradle : How to run externalNativeBuildDebug task after a custom task

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on Android project which uses `build.gradle`. I want to run `externalNativeBuildDebug` task after a custom task.

In `build.gradle`, I specify:

```
task mytask()
{
    println 'hello'
}


tasks.getByName("externalNativeBuildDebug").mustRunAfter(mytask)
```

But gradle throws this error :

```
Task with name 'externalNativeBuildDebug' not found in project ':app'.
```

I have defined `externalNativeBuild` block in `android{}` block

```
externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                path file('CMakeLists.txt')
                version '3.18.1'
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to get `externalNativeBuildDebug` task and set its dependency?